# How can I pass MPI_Datatypes into functions in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, types, mpi, hpc

I want to try this but I don't know what to write in the function's input parameters.

```
void receiveCar(int value, ? Type2){
        MPI_Status status;
        cars = new car*[value]; //this is an array of Car (dyn. Allocated)
        for (int i=0;i<value;i++) cars[i] = new car(0,0,0);

 /* Here I want to receive the object BUT I need the datatype which is define elsewhere */
        MPI_Recv(cars[1], 1, Type2, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

     for (int i=0;i<value;i++) delete cars[i];
     delete [] cars;


}
```

Comment: `void receiveCar(int value, MPI_Datatype Type2)` is fine. Note MPI send/recv `struct` and not C++ `class` via derived datatypes. You might also want to explore higher level C++ abstractions such as `Boost.MPI` or `libelemental`

Comment: I've been told that is a nightmare for send/recv Classes in C++. To be honest this is what I am trying to do...